How can I save results of multiple R models to a csv?
I was able to create a tibble with results of 12 linear models as lists with the code below. These are linear models between average monthly flow (MMF) and watershed area (DRAINAGE_AREA_GROSS) and the output can bee seen in the picture.
MMF_reggression <- flow_average %>% group_by(Month) %>%
 do(model = lm(MMF ~ DRAINAGE_AREA_GROSS, data = .))

I want to export the coefficients of the lists to CSV, but I am having trouble dealing with them because they are in this tibble.
So no the end of the world but would like to not have manually put those into a .csv. Any solutions to this would be greatly appreciated.

I can't get approaches like this to work:
write.csv(coef(MMF_reggression[[,2]]), file = 'regionalregression.csv')

I can save results in a text file with:
sink("model_summary.txt")
print(MMF_reggression[[2]])
sink()


I'd recommend broom::tidy() for translating your results into a workflow-friendly format.
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>%
 do(model = lm(hp ~ mpg, data = .)) %>%
 mutate(tbl = list(tidy(model))) %>%
 unnest(tbl) %>%
 select(-model)

# A tibble: 6 × 6
    cyl term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1     4 (Intercept)   147.       35.6      4.14  0.00252
2     4 mpg            -2.43      1.32    -1.84  0.0984 
3     6 (Intercept)   164.      147.       1.12  0.313  
4     6 mpg            -2.12      7.40    -0.286 0.786  
5     8 (Intercept)   294.       84.3      3.49  0.00445
6     8 mpg            -5.65      5.51    -1.02  0.326  

You can then select() whichever columns you want to keep and write them out to the CSV.
I would suggest
lmList(hp~mpg|cyl, data = mtcars) |> broom.mixed::tidy()

but the tidy method appears to be broken ATM ... ???

Unlisting and summarizing first should work with write.csv if model has the coefficients variable.
library(dplyr)

write.csv(MMF_reggression %>% 
            rowwise() %>% 
            summarize(coeff = list(coef(model))) %>% 
            tidyr::unnest_wider(coeff), 
  file = "regionalregression.csv")


Yes the model has coefficients. The second one worked great! thanks. The first code block only had the intercept and was having trouble pointing it to the slope coefficient.

K, good, glad it worked, gonna remove the first then.
